# Reduction formula question

Tags: integration

If $I_n=\int_0^1(\ln x)^n \, dx$
a)Prove that $I_n=-nI_{n-1}$
b)Deduce that $I_n=(-1)^nn!$

I have done part a. No idea how to approach part b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove it by induction.

Inductive step : Assuming that $I_n=(-1)^nn!$, we have
$$\begin{align}I_{n+1}&=-(n+1)I_n\\&=-(n+1)\times (-1)^n\cdot n!\\&=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot (n+1)!.\end{align}$$

Comment: Edited. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user140161: I don't know another way.